# How to change a specific column name in case of using @JoinTable

Tags: java, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

This is the sample code

```
public class Address{
@Column(name = "STREET_NAME")
private String street;
@Column(name = "CITY_NAME")
private String city;
@Column(name = "STATE_NAME")
private String state;
@Column(name = "PIN_CODE")
private int pin;
//setters and getters
}

public class User {

@Id 
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="user_id")
private int userId;

@ElementCollection
@JoinTable(name="USER_ADDRESS",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID"))
private Set<Address> listOfAddresses=new HashSet();
//setters and getters
}
```

I have no access/modify Address class using @Column annotation. @JoinColumn is only changing the primary key name alone.
Now, how can Ichange the street name of Address from User class?

Answer (score 0):

Use a orm.xml to override mappings. Also see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-jpa-xml-files